# Xcode8 doesn't launch the last version of the app in device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10, xcode8

Since updated to Xcode 8 when I launch my app in the device (iPhone or iPad both with iOS 10), it launches a version not updated of the app.

But if I launch the app in the simulator, it launches the updated app...

Things that i tried: Clean the project, clean the build folder, uninstall the apps in the devices, reboot Xcode...

Any idea with this? It will go crazy!

Comment: What happens when you increment the build number? Have you tried it with a blank new project?

Comment: Just tried increment the build number  and got same result, but with a blank new project is working

Comment: Manually delete the APP form the device clean your project and delete derived data -> then try to run again

Comment: Same result... :(

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't have time to know what it is happening here, so I created a new project and moved all the files from the older project. Now it is working.

I know it isn't the best solution but i can't spend more hours into this.

Thanks all for the responses!